# Installed python script warns not on PATH

Tags: bash, python

I have installed a script using pip, after installing the script returned the following error:

```
 WARNING: The script testapp is installed in '/home/pi/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

How can I fix this? The script is not executable in any directory because of this. I have tried adding `export PATH=/home/pi/dir:$PATH` to the end of my `.bashrc` but this doesn't appear to make the script available anywhere, so the changes aren't correct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing that .local which is a hidden directory.

PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/.local/bin;export $PATH